# Jetpack Compose - stop focused elements from stealing back presses?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I've got some elements that have focus in a bottom sheet. I want to collapse the bottom sheet when the system back button is pressed, which is easy enough:

```kotlin
  BackHandler(enabled = bottomSheetState.isExpanded) {
    scope.launch {
      bottomSheetState.collapse()
    }
  }
```

The problem is, if an element is focused in the bottom sheet, the back handler's logic only gets triggered after pressing the back button *twice*: once to remove focus from the element (outlined text field) and once more to trigger the collapse.

I've tried using the `LocalFocusManager.current` to combine clearing focus when back is pressed, but the back logic isn't triggered until the element has already lost focus.

I can clear focus on collapse, so I guess the **real** problem is having to press back twice when the sheet is 1) visible and 2) has a child element focused.

Is there a way to stop focused elements from superseding my back logic?

Comment: found any solution to this @Carter ?

Comment: I haven't found one yet. It sort of fell to the bottom of my list of issues, but I'll update if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Carter I have found the issue on the official tracker find the link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192433071). It has been fixed in [compose 1.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.1.0-alpha03) but since the library is an alpha candidate I don't know how safe it would be for production. There is also a workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849179/6938847)

a cleaner approach would be :

1. Create this manager

```
/***
 * Compose issue to be fixed in alpha 1.03
 * track from here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192433071?pli=1
 * current work around
 */
class KeyBoardManager(context: Context) {

    private val activity = context as Activity
    private var keyboardDismissListener: KeyboardDismissListener? = null

    private abstract class KeyboardDismissListener(
        private val rootView: View,
        private val onKeyboardDismiss: () -> Unit
    ) : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        private var isKeyboardClosed: Boolean = false
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val r = Rect()
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
            val screenHeight = rootView.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom
            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                // 0.15 ratio is right enough to determine keypad height.
                isKeyboardClosed = false
            } else if (!isKeyboardClosed) {
                isKeyboardClosed = true
                onKeyboardDismiss.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

    fun attachKeyboardDismissListener(onKeyboardDismiss: () -> Unit) {
        val rootView = activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
        keyboardDismissListener = object : KeyboardDismissListener(rootView, onKeyboardDismiss) {}
        keyboardDismissListener?.let {
            rootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(it)
        }
    }

    fun release() {
        val rootView = activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
        keyboardDismissListener?.let {
            rootView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(it)
        }
        keyboardDismissListener = null
    }
}
```

2. Create this composable

```
@Composable
fun AppKeyboardFocusManager() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    DisposableEffect(key1 = context) {
        val keyboardManager = KeyBoardManager(context)
        keyboardManager.attachKeyboardDismissListener {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        }
        onDispose {
            keyboardManager.release()
        }
    }
}
```

3. Apply on application level

```
setContent {
        AppKeyboardFocusManager()
        YourAppMaterialTheme {
            ...
        }
    }
```