# cannot back from Activity after request focus and setonkeyEvent using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```
        val requester = FocusRequester()
    Box(
        Modifier
            .onKeyEvent {
                if (it.isCtrlPressed && it.key == Key.A){

                    println("Ctrl + A is pressed")
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            .focusRequester(requester)
            .focusable()
            .size(10.dp)
    )
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        requester.requestFocus()
    }
```

after launchedEffect and request focus, I need backpressed twice to leave page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear TextField focus when closing the keyboard and prevent two back presses needed to exit app in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389802/how-to-clear-textfield-focus-when-closing-the-keyboard-and-prevent-two-back-pres)

Comment: It's a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192433071), will be fixed in compose `1.1.0`