# Jetpack compose soft keyboard opens up when switching apps

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

A weird bug in my current app that was created using Jetpack Compose.

**Issue**: Once the soft keyboard is opened in the app, due to any screen with `TextField`, the keyboard is shown every time when switching from a different app to this one.

[image: Video]

Unable to provide a minimal reproducible code as I can't figure out which code is causing this issue and I noticed this quite late as I didn't expect a bug when switching apps.

The whole source code is on Github:
https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/finance-manager/tree/main/codebase/android.

Kindly comment if any particular code might help.

---

Adding keyboard-related code I can think of which might have an impact.

The keyboard is hidden whenever composable navigation happens,

Using `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController`,

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
keyboardController?.hide()
```

Comment: How is `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController` used?

Comment: I think it is more related to `FocusRequester` inside `AddTransactionScreenView`

Comment: Looks like a bug, related to the fact that text field is still focused after keyboard is hidden, which is default Android behaviour. You can use [my modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420874/3585796), which takes the focus off the TF after hiding the keyboard.

Comment: [Reported it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227300835)

Comment: i have the same issues, downgrading compose and accompanist to 1.2.0-alpha04 works fine

Comment: I have a similar issue any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get any solutions so far. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in compose (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225541817). It's fixed as of compose 1.2.0-beta02

Comment: Yes, seems to be fixed in `1.2.0-beta02`.