# How to clear focus on keyboard close in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to clear focus on TextField() when user close Keyboard in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear TextField focus when closing the keyboard and prevent two back presses needed to exit app in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389802/how-to-clear-textfield-focus-when-closing-the-keyboard-and-prevent-two-back-pres)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to monitor the keyboard status:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847559/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-opening-and-closing-in-jetpack-compose
@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<Boolean> {
    val keyboardState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val view = LocalView.current
    val viewTreeObserver = view.viewTreeObserver
    DisposableEffect(viewTreeObserver) {
        val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            keyboardState.value = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
                ?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: true
        }
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
        onDispose { viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener) }
    }
    return keyboardState
}
```

Then you can remove focus, for example, from the entire composable screen at once using [`FocusManager.clearFocus`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/FocusManager#clearfocus):

```
// Clear focus if keyboard was hidden by user
val isKeyboardOpen by KeyboardUtil.keyboardAsState()
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
if (!isKeyboardOpen) focusManager.clearFocus()
```