# Jetpack compose avoid keyboard effect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I avoid keyboard effect when it dismisses and in some screens it happens both when opening and dismissing keyboard.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "keyboard effect"? If you're talking about input pointer, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420874/3585796)

Comment: @PhilDukhov I mean the effect that causes the whole screen to jump. The effect when keyboard is closing seems to pull the screen down with keyboard

Comment: Most probably you question had no reaction because you haven't provided a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I haven't faced such side effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was because of 'animateContentSize' modifier on following page. it caused this effect

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is because my activity has following setting which causes bug from compose, if remove it, the problems disappeared.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

But other place needed this, so waiting for the fix from jetpack compose.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230652481