# Android Compose TextField and focus on back button click

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to remove focus from a TextField on back button click. Keyboard is gone, but a TextField still has a focus, cursor etc.

I've saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389802/how-to-clear-textfield-focus-when-closing-the-keyboard-and-prevent-two-back-pres), bo I am not getting onFocusEvent, because it still is focused.

```
            var textFieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
            TextField(
                value = textFieldValue.value,
                onValueChange = { textFieldValue.value = it},
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this be using `LocalFocusManager` and intercepting with `onKeyEvent`. There's a catch though, while the code is correct, `onKeyEvent` is only triggered when keyboard is closed, so in this case it'd behave like:

- first back press: closes keyboard;
- second back press: triggers `onKeyEvent` and clears focus;

```kotlin
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
var textFieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
TextField(
    value = textFieldValue.value,
    onValueChange = { textFieldValue.value = it},
    modifier = Modifier
        .onKeyEvent { event ->
            if (event.key.nativeKeyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
                true
            } else {
                false
        
            }
        }
)
```

There's an open issue for back not being intercepted when keyboard is open: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241705563

Comment: I've tried it before. But as you are saying onKeyEvent does not trigger on first back pressed. I needed to clear focus as soon as keyboard gone. I've used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70506309/3797879. Not ideal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack have some unexpected behavior with reopen keyboard and focus when you press back button. The closest to regular behavior is something like this.

```
 val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }


TextField(
            value = userInput, 
            onValueChange = {
            userInput = it
        }, 
            modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable()
)
```

When add focusable you can press again back button and focus will gone. Also the order is important.